# (python) How to convert a dictionary value into a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

My problem is as follows:

I have a txt-file that holds nothing but a dictionary with one single key. The value to that one, single key is a huge list containing dictionaries as list entries. First key:value pair for comparison:

`"data": [{"type": "utl", "id": "53150", "attributes": {"timestamp": "T13:00:00Z", "count": 0.0}}, [...etc.]`

I tried the following method to convert the value of the single-keyed dictionary into a list by calling the .values method and then using list():

`list_variable = list(dict_variable.values())`

But it seems that this just converts the value into a list with just one index, for when I try to call index 0 the file crashes (list is too big) and if I try to call index 1 I get a KeyError stating that the index is out of range. (My current idea is to frist convert it into a list and THEN into a DataFrame)
I'm a bloody beginner and have no idea what else I could try. What am I missing? 
Thanks a lot in advance! fpr your helpful comments!

Comment: Read this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html. Might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like a json to me. try using `pandas.json_normalize`

```
d = {"data": [{"type": "utl", "id": "53150", "attributes": {"timestamp": "T13:00:00Z", "count": 0.0}}]}
pd.json_normalize(d['data'])

  type     id attributes.timestamp  attributes.count
0  utl  53150           T13:00:00Z               0.0
```

Comment: that worked indeed! didn't know that method yet. thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the below codes help you?

**test.txt**

```
"data": [{"type": "utl", "id": "53150", "attributes": {"timestamp": "T13:00:00Z", "count": 0.0}}, {"type": "utl2", "id": "53151", "attributes": {"timestamp": "T12:00:00Z", "count": 1.0}}]
```

```
from re import findall
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open("test.txt") as f:
    print(json_normalize(eval(findall("{.+}", f.read())[0])))
```

**Output:**

```
   type     id attributes.timestamp  attributes.count
0   utl  53150           T13:00:00Z               0.0
1  utl2  53151           T12:00:00Z               1.0
```